# how to dynamically put UIBarButtonItem on the NavigationBar in storyboard ?

Tags: storyboard, uibarbuttonitem, navigationbar

My app is being built under storyboard and its navigation controller.
I am trying to put a bar button on the right of navigation bar, but it doesn't seem to be easy at all.
The codes look like this...

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Edit" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(barBtnPressed)];

//        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
```

I did everything what I could try, but no luck.

Any advice ?

Comment: `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;` is correct as `navigationItem` is a property of your view controller. When are you setting the `rightBarButtonItem` property normally you'd set it in `viewDidLoad` of the view controller that is appearing on top in your navigation controller stack.

Comment: Thanks for your quick advice. I put those codes into viewDidLoad, but no luck. Its use would be different with storyboard? What am I missing?

Comment: Does the `UIViewController` object on the story board have the right class set so that it uses your custom class?

Comment: The root view is Navigation Controller and many other child view controllers and grand child views. This codes belongs to one of child view controllers. No problems with navigation control but this issue.

Comment: As this code 'self.navigationItem.title = @"Title";' doesn't work, I think Storyboard's navigation controller should be handled differently than the one with xib. Just my guess. :)

Comment: Well, the code doesn't change at all, but maybe just drag a bar button item to the navigation bar in your storyboard and be done with it :)

Comment: You can check the link provided in this Answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250419/custom-pressed-uibarbuttonitem-backgrounds

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to do it in Storyboard, rather than programatically, you can place your UIBarButtonItem (it will default to the left side) and then use a flexible space bar button item to move the BarButtonItem over to the right side.