# Change BarButtonItem icon on click

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, uibarbuttonitem, ios9.1

I'm trying to create a counter. The idea is quite simple, you click on "play" button and once you click it should disappear and become a "pause" icon, which would trigger a different action.

I thought setting a var for counter status and changing the icon (with only one button) would do the trick but I don't have a clue how can I set the button image for "pause" or any other that appears in the drop down menu when you are creating it from the storyboard panel.

Here the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIBarButtonItem!
var timer = NSTimer()
var currentStatus = "stopped"


@IBAction func playAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (currentStatus == "stopped"){
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("increaseTimer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        currentStatus = "running"
        // change button icon (playButton) to Stop
    }
    else {
        currentStatus = "stopped"
        timer.invalidate()
       // change button icon (playButton) to Play
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your bar button item's outlet if you have one? If you don't have a connected outlet, I advise you to make one.

Comment: Yes, its connected, I have edited it and now you can see it (playButton var)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the icon of a Bar Button when pressed in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769005/how-to-change-the-icon-of-a-bar-button-when-pressed-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the button style like this:

```
//setButton to play
yourBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play, target: self, action: "TheMethodThatTheButtonShouldCall"), animated: true)
//setButton to stop
yourBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Stop, target: self, action: "TheMethodThatTheButtonShouldCall"), animated: true)
```

Comment: Am I missing some imports? it says unresolved identifier 'BarButtonitem' :S

Comment: Nope, @HarsalBhavsar. I tried:

UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play, target: self, action: "TheMethodThatTheButtonShouldCall")

which is apparently correct and it is not working at all. 
Actually I am starting to think that it is not possible.. :/

Comment: Can i have screen shot of your screen?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the button style with array like this:

```
   func addCustomNavigationItemAtLeftAndRightSide(leftButtonItems:[UIBarButtonItem], rightButtonItems:[UIBarButtonItem]) {

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = leftButtonItems
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = rightButtonItems
 }
```

You can use with style like this:

```
  let leftButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "ic_top_back"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "onBackButtonClicked:")
  addCustomNavigationItemAtLeftAndRightSide([leftButtonItem], rightButtonItems: [])
```