# Swift - UIToolbar item selected state

Tags: ios, swift, uitoolbar

I have this toolbar in my navigation controller. Now what I am trying to do is when the user selects an item (`UIBarButtonItem`) in my toolbar, have that item highlighted with a background colour until either the user deselects the item or selects another item. How would I do this?

Here are my selector methods for each item of the toolbar, I connected them via storyboard:

```
@IBAction func addText(sender: AnyObject) {
        annotationSelected = 3
}

@IBAction func drawCircle(sender: AnyObject) {
    annotationSelected = 1
}

@IBAction func drawRectangle(sender: AnyObject) {
    annotationSelected = 2
}

@IBAction func drawStamp(sender: AnyObject) {
    annotationSelected = 4
}
```

This is all I have done. Here is a screenshot of my toolbar:

[image]

Here is what I got:

```
@IBOutlet var textToolButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBOutlet var circleToolButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBOutlet var rectangleToolButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBOutlet var stampToolButton: UIBarButtonItem!
```

then

```
textToolButton.target = self
        textToolButton.style = .Done
        textToolButton.action = #selector(ViewController.barButtonPressed)

        let selectedBackgroundColor = UIImage(color: .redColor())

        textToolButton.setBackgroundImage(selectedBackgroundColor, forState: UIControlState.Highlighted, style: .Done, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

and then the method

```
func barButtonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        print(sender)
        annotationSelected = sender.tag
    }
```

background is still not changing color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a same question. May be can help you.
[custom-pressed-uibarbuttonitem-backgrounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250419/custom-pressed-uibarbuttonitem-backgrounds)

I find a easy method to do. You can dray a button to the toolBar,and you will see like this.

And you should change the button's type and Image. 
[storyboard screenshot](http://7xsmd8.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/QQ20160719-1@2x.png)

then you should link the button to your viewController.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textToolButton: UIButton!
```

and you can do.

```
let selectedBackgroundColor = UIImage(color: .redColor())
textToolButton.setBackgroundImage(selectedBackgroundColor, forState: .Highlighted)
```

May be I can help you.

Comment: I can't upload image. Because I don't have 10 reputaions.

Comment: This is for UIButtons not UIBarButtonItem

Comment: I'm sorry,I can't express my idea.

    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: customButton];

so We can change customButton to achieve this goals.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way you could do it, is create an overall function where you pass in the button that's been selected. Something like this:

```
    var allButtons = [button1, button2, button3, button4]

    func resetTabBar (buttonSelected:UIButton) {
        for button in allButtons {
            if button == buttonSelected {
                button.backgroundColor = "Black"
            }
            else {
                button.backgroundColor = "Blue"
            }
        }

    }
```

And then in your functions you've created, just pass in the sender like so:

```
@IBAction func addText(sender: AnyObject) {

    resetTabBar(sender)

}
```

Note: This is assuming you have outlets for all of your buttons. If you don't, add them.

Comment: This will not work for UIBarButtonItem, the do not have backgroundColor

Comment: The use case and the code works, the user can modify the code however they want.